# Join two tables given a between condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables, one is my result table where I have a column "Date" and another "Description".
The other one is my configuration table, where I have "Begin Day","Begin Month" and "End Day","End Month". The only way to join both tables is using the date, where the column "Date" from table Results must be between the "Begin" day and month and "End" day and month from the configuration table.

T_Result |
ID |
Date |
Description

T_Configuration |
ID |
Description |
Begin_Day |
Begin_Month |
End_Day |
End_Month

How can I do it?

Comment: @DaleK imagine T_Result: 1, 07/07/2020, Result_Desc
T_Configuration: 1, Config_Desc, 1,5,1,10
So in the Configuration table in the begin day I have 1 and month 5, in the end day I have 1 and month 10, I must do the join where my T_Result Date must be between my Begin day and month, and end day and month.

Comment: [edit] any improvements directly into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer expressed as a proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM T_Result r JOIN
     T_Configuration c
     ON DAY(r.Date) BETWEEN c.Begin_Day AND c.End_Day AND
        MONTH(r.Date) BETWEEN c.Begin_Month AND c.End_Month;
```

Also note the use of table aliases to simplify writing the query.

Answer (score 1):

It fits to SQL Server. Pay attention to brackets!

```
SELECT * 
FROM [table_name_1]
INNER JOIN[table_name_2]
ON (strftime('%d',[table_name_1].Date) BETWEEN [table_name_2].[Begin-Day] AND [table_name_2].[End-Day])
AND (strftime('%m', [table_name_1].Date) BETWEEN [table_name_2].[Begin-Month] AND [table_name_2].[End-Month])
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Begin_Month & End_Month columns are numeric,

```
SELECT * FROM T_Result, T_Configuration 
WHERE 
(DAY(T_Result.Date) BETWEEN T_Configuration.Begin_Day AND T_Configuration.End_Day) AND
(MONTH(T_Result.Date) BETWEEN T_Configuration.Begin_Month AND T_Configuration.End_Month)
```